# How many ways to put $30$ indistinguishable balls in three urns if each urn has at least $5$ balls?

Tags: combinatorics

30 indistinguishable balls are deposited at random in 3 different urns.
How many ways can balls be deposited, if each urn has at least 5 balls?

Is this a permutation, or combination problem. I can solve this if there was no restriction, but how do I deal with the "at least 5".

Comment: Hint: You know how 15 of the balls are distributed. In how many ways can you distribute the remaining 15 among 3 urns?

Comment: If the balls are indistinguishable, place $5$ balls in each urn, which reduces the problem to distributing $15$ indistinguishable balls to three different urns.  If the balls are distinguishable, use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to exclude those distributions in which fewer than five balls are placed in one or more of the urns.  The problem is much easier if the balls are indistinguishable.

Comment: The balls are indistinguishable.

Comment: Please edit your question to say that.

Comment: I changed the problem to "at least" 5 balls in each urn. Do I assume that there are 5 balls in each earn and not more than that?

Comment: Placing five balls in each urn guarantees that there will be at least five balls in each urn after the remaining balls are distributed.

Answer (score 2):

Since at least five balls are placed in each urn, place five balls in each urn.  This guarantees that there are at least five balls in each urn.

This reduces the problem to distributing the remaining $15$ balls to three urns.  Let $x_k$ be the number of remaining balls that are placed in the $k$th urn.  Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 15 \tag{1}$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  Therefore, the number of ways we can distribute $30$ indistinguishable balls to three urns if at least five balls are placed in each urn is the number of solutions of equation 1 in the nonnegative integers.

Comment: So I used a (n+k-1)C(k-1) = 17!/15!.2! = 136 ways to do it

Comment: @Ani.K  That is correct.